# How to write good blog post tags

Tags: seo, tags, meta-keywords, blog

It seems that you have three choices in deciding how you write tags for your blog posts:

1. Make them user friendly
2. Make them highly searchable
3. Combo of the two

For example, let's say that I have a blog post that has write-ups on the top 10 ipad apps for business travel (e.g., Evernote, Dragon Diction, Instapaper, etc.).

1. *User friendly tags:* ipad apps, business travel
2. *Searchable keywords (analyzed with Google Keyword Analyzer):* ipad apps, ipad travel apps, evernote ipad, instapaper, instapaper ipad
3. *Combo:* ipad apps, ipad travel apps

So my question comes down to this: which is really the best choice -- 1, 2 or 3?

Note: this visible post tags will also serve as the meta keywords for the post page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User firendly is the same thing as highly searchable. What people are searching for are always the user friendly tags. [Usability is a basic tennant of SEO](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/13007/1253). So option three is the only real option and thus the correct choice.

Comment: i understand your point...i think in some cases blog editors will use their tags as alternative "menu" navigation scheme..this is what i meant by #1.  But I like your point: whatever is highly searchable is the same as user friendly.  Well said.