# Is it better in terms of SEO if I develop my Website meant for marketing my service on a regular .com domain compared to a wordpress site?

Tags: seo, wordpress

Basically I am asking is whether Google et al are going to *treat* my webpages developed through wordpress in the same way as they would treat other websites with a *.com? Also, as far as SEO goes do I have to jump through some additional hoops if I am working with a wordpress site ? Would I have any advantages instead ?

Comment: You need to clarify your question. Are you talking about a .com site of yours that happens to have been *built* using WordPress, or are you asking whether *hosting with WordPress.com* will help or hurt your search ranking?

Answer (score 5):

Your question is a little vague. Are you asking about using a hosted WordPress blog (on wordpress.com) vs hosted? Or are you asking if WordPress itself has any SEO benefits over static websites?

One of the major ranking factors Google uses to establish rankings is something called "domain authority." If you are using a subdomain of WordPress (e.g. mysite.wordpress.com) instead of your own domain URL (e.g. www.mysite.com) then you are sacrificing that domain authority. Each page will have to rank on its own merit. You are always much better off with your own top-level domain.

In terms of WordPress as a platform, it has several inherent SEO benefits. First, it supports URL rewriting which makes it easy to integrate your keywords into the URL - an important ranking factor. Second, there are lots of really helpful and effective SEO plugins. Finally, the more (quality) pages your site has, the more the search engines will like you. WordPress itself doesn't accomplish this, but it is one of the easier-to-use content management systems out there and makes it dead simple to publish content. None of these is exclusive to WordPress, but in my opinion it is the simplest "out of the box" solutions available right now.

Comment: Actually I was asking about both. But right now I am wondering about your comment about "domain authority". How can I use wordpress and still have my own domain ?

Comment: You use the self-hosted version from WordPress.org. You can install it yourself, or (better yet) just sign up for a web host that will install it for you. But you can also use the paid version of WordPress.com and use your own domain name. It's a little more expensive than other web hosts.

Comment: Domain authority it **not** a **major** ranking factor. Plus web pages are ranked on their own merits. "Domain authority" would only be used to weed out spam ,not determine page quality.

Comment: Absolutely untrue, John. It accounts for approximately 44% of ranking factors: http://www.seomoz.org/article/search-ranking-factors

Answer (score 1):

Most hosting providers have a push button setup to install WordPress. I use Hostgator and it is super simple from the cPanel. You want to register your own domain name with a .com,.org, or .net. If you are serious about seo then stay away from the other extensions. WordPress itself is inherently decent with seo, but you will want to do some things like install all-in-one seo plugin. This will help you ensure your meta tags have the right info in them.

Comment: Do not use a _install service_ from a hosting provider. These are often out of date and hard to update.

Comment: I will partially agree to that. If you use a reputable hosting company, you normally don't have problems. I personally have never had trouble with hostgator or Inmotion hosting. For those who know Nothing about FTP this is the easiest way.

Answer (score 0):

A hosted blogger blog has equal footing with a .com hosted on a dedicated server. Quality of content is what determines where a page ranks. Not the TLD or software used for the website.

If your content is hosted on Blogger and it is high quality you will naturally attract quality links from related websites. These are very valuable in Google's eye and will boost your ranking accordingly.

FYI, one thing many people get confused about with SEO is how Google actually works. What most people fail to consider is that there are two parts to Google's algorithm: page ranking and spam control. Matt Cutts is head of the spam control team. That's why you hear him occasionally "hearing" about ranking factors. That's because he's not part of the team that actually determines them. And spam control algorithms do **not** determine a page's ranking. That part of the algorithm tries to weed out junk and cheaters. Things like domain authority won't help you rank better. It just makes you less likely to be considered low quality.

On the other hand, things like quality incoming links *do* determine your pages' rankings. **That's why quality content is king and always will be.**

[Read this to learn more about SEO](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/12960/seo-how-to-separate-fact-from-fiction/13007#13007).

Answer (score 0):

Using hosting services like BlueHost where you can install WordPress from within BlueHost, work well and enable you to use your domain name of choice if you purchase your domain name through them as well. Additionally, WordPress has many great SEO plugins that you can use to help track and hopefully lead to increasing SEO rankings. WassUp is a very helpful option.

In general, avoid including ".wordpess" as part of your domain name. Your target market will perceive your website and business as more professional. Best of luck.

Comment: WordPress.com allows you to use custom domains.