# high number of nofollow links bad?

Tags: seo, nofollow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ratio of No-follow & Do-follow Backlinks](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/12690/ratio-of-no-follow-do-follow-backlinks)

I've been playing with seomoz's tools and it seems like our site has a high number of nofollow links.

from what I understand this is because a lot of blogs will make the links used in comments nofollow links, thereby not affecting our ranking? is this a problem and what can be done about it?

Answer (score 2):

Nofollow links are ignored by search engines, so that they don't increase the ranking of the target page. It's meant to reduce the impact of, for example, public comments on blogs, which might contain spam links. With nofollow, they don't count for search engine ranking, so that spammers have less incentive to spam.

Nofollow cannot affect the ranking of the site containing the links. If there's a nofollow link within the site, the target page ranking will not increase because of that link, but the 'lost' ranking is applied to other links (without nofollow) instead.

Finally, most SEO practices don't actually affect search engines. Just make sure to create a consistent site for your users, and search engines will do the right thing.

Comment: ok, so it's not because a tool like seomoz says you have a lot of nofollow links that there is a problem ?

Answer (score -2):

Search engine follows only do-follow links. No-follow links would be not followed by Search engines. So any website have many no-follow links, may be search engine will ignore the website.

now days, search engines are more powerful about links and content also. So do seo with quality but not with spamming.