# Should be there nofollow vs. dofollow backlink ratio?

Tags: seo, backlinks, nofollow, dofollow

[Ratio of No-follow & Do-follow Backlinks](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/12690/ratio-of-no-follow-do-follow-backlinks) asked about obtaining backlinks, I am asking about giving backlink.

Most of my posts are list posts like "Best Forums", "Best Sites to Learn Photoshop", "Best WordPress tutorials", etc.

So every post include 20+ external links. Will there be a problem if I make all those links `nofollow`?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you want to assign `rel=nofollow` to these sites?  Are you concerned about 'leaking' link equity?  Don't forget that Google (maybe others too) factor in your outgoing links as part of their ranking algorithm.  If you are ranking to reputable sites, it may be a mistake to `rel=nofollow` such links.  I can only assume you are looking to `rel=nofollow` duplicate links?!